# How to go back to application from a bookmark icon at homescreen in ios?

Tags: ios, safari, bookmarks, homescreen

friends i am working on a iphone app which takes name and image and then shows it in safari. now user can bookmarks it. it will become a home screen icon. Now i want that if user taps on that icon my Native app should be open. but i am not finding any way to revert it on my application. please help me.

Comment: Hm... Can you elaborate more or post some screen shots?

Comment: @voyage11 ,when user give his name and a image, it will save on server and on a button's target it seems on safari web page , then i crate a bookmarks and it become a icon on iphone's main screen. so now i want that when a user tap that icon it should go to my native app.... hope you understood.!!

Answer (score 1):

You can define [a custom URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) for your app. Then you can program your web page to automatically forward to a URL with this scheme when the user comes to your website via the home screen icon. It should then launch your app.

Comment: Use the link above for the iOS part (you have to do the coding yourself; this is not a "write my code"-site). Depending on your web server setup implement the [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection).